# boost b2 build 64 bit results in argument error missing argument

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, b2

I am trying to build 64 bit libraries using boost's b2. I followed all the steps to the tee but I keep getting an annoying error about a missing argument setup-script.

Here is my user-config.jam file that I put into my HOME directory:

```
# -------------------
# MSVC configuration.
# -------------------

# Configure msvc (default version, searched for in standard locations and PATH).
# using msvc ;

# Configure specific msvc version (searched for in standard locations and PATH).
using msvc : 12.0 : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe" ;

# ---------------------
# Python configuration.
# ---------------------

# Configure specific Python version.
# using python : 3.5 : C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Anaconda3 : C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Anaconda3\\include : C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Anaconda3\\Lib ;

using python 
    : 3.5                   # Version
    : "C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"      # Python Path
    : "C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Anaconda3\\include"         # include path
    : "C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Anaconda3\\libs"            # lib path(s)
    : <define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
    ;
```

I then run this command in my root boost directory:

```
./b2 msvc address-model=64 stage
```

Then I get this error:

```
*** argument error
* rule maybe-rewrite-setup ( toolset : setup-script : setup-options : version : rewrite-setup ? )
* called with: ( msvc :  :  : 12.0 :  )
* missing argument setup-script
```

The funny thing is that if I get rid of the x86_amd64 directory in the msvc configuration line like this:

```
using msvc : 12.0 : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" ;
```

It begins to build.

How do I make boost build the 64 bit version of the libraries, correctly?